# Android emulator's GPS location gives wrong time

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps

I am testing an Android GPS tracking application in the Emulator and I am running into a problem when trying to figure out if the last known location is stale or not. 
 
Getting the system time gives me the correct time, but when I call `location.getTime()` for the last known location the time returned is off by a few hours. I did some more testing and found out that every time I send a GPS location from the Emulator control tab in Eclipse (similar to geo fix), the location's time is advanced by one second. This makes no sense at all! I would appreciate any insights into this problem.

Comment: Interesting and repeatable here too. It gets the date right, the time starts at 12:00:00, then advances to 12:00:01 etc with each successive geo fix. My timezone is GMT. I'd say it's a bug in the emulator.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. When sending "manual" coords to the emulator via DDMS, I get a time that is way off (starts at correct date, but at 00:00, and advances by one second each time I send a new time).

Answer (score 3):

As discussed this appears to be a bug in the emulator (I was able to repeat it as well). I filed a bug report at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27272 if anyone wants to add details, star it, and/or follow along.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in the `ToT dev branch` for `API 26`. We will cherry-pick this fix to other branches and hopefully the public available system images will see the bug fix in the near future.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36942593) they will re-open to examine.