# Time from location fix using emulator is off

Tags: android, android-emulator, gps, ddms

I'm writing some android code to test out the geolocation libraries and I'm running into a problem with the android emulator.  I am creating a LocationListener and when LocationListener::onLocationChanged is called I check the time of the passed in Location object to compare it to the current time.  I use the DDMS emulator control window to change the location to trigger the call to onLocationChanged.  Here is the code that I use in the onLocationChanged method to compare the passed in location time to the current time ("location" is the location that is passed into onLocationChanged):

```
float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float lateness = (curTime - location.getTime()) / 1000;
```

The problem I'm having is that the time I get from location using getTime is always way off of the current time (curTime) even though the time between when I set the location using DDMS and the time I look at it in the debugger is a matter of seconds.  Usually the difference is several hours, and sometimes the time from location is several hours ahead of the current time (so the time of the location fix occurs several hours in the future?!?).  Additionally, the time diffference is not consistent.  The documentation for the call to Location::getTime and System.currentTimeMillies both say that the returned time is given in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC, so it shouldn't be an issue of using different time zones.  Is this a known bug with the emulator or is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GPS time is actually different from time on the device. So, they can differ by a huge amount. Wiki has a nice explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_time#Timekeeping)

Answer (score 0):

More information about this can be found at [Android emulator's GPS location gives wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889487/android-emulators-gps-location-gives-wrong-time) as well as the bug report link. Additionally [Android problem finding out how recent latest GPS fix is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418344/android-problem-finding-out-how-recent-latest-gps-fix-is/4481665#4481665) may be worth reading as well as to why system time and GPS time won't match.